# Is it possible to install the Unity 2D Panel in Kubuntu without pulling in all of Unity's dependencies?

Tags: 11.10, unity, kubuntu, unity-2d, panel

I would like to avoid installing Gnome dependencies, if possible. I figured this is possible as Unity 2D is written in Qt. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to install a package with only the *required* dependencies, not the *recommended* ones (which are usually installed by default):

`sudo apt-get -o APT::Install-Recommends=0 install package1 package2 package3`

While Unity 2D *may* work without some of the required dependencies, it's a very dangerous zone to be meddling in. You can use `dpkg` with forced removal to remove the ones you think don't matter, after installation with the above.